# IIS App Pool Monitoring Infinite Loops (or in-appropriate load)

Tags: web-services, iis, iis-7, application-pool

Im just wondering if there is anyway I can handle when our webservice might get stuck in an infinite loop. I know the first answer is not to have an infinite loop and we have tested the system and no loops should occur. But just for a fallback is there a way on putting something on the IIS app pool to say if the CPU has been running at say 99% for more than 1 minute than recycle the app pool?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no IIS-built-in way of doing something like that (the recycle options allow you to recycle at a set time each day, or after a set number of minutes, based on hitting virtual or private memory limits, or based on hitting a particular number of requests - nothing CPU-ish).

You could build your own monitor that would watch for certain events (like CPU going above 99% for a minute) and causes a recycle to happen (there are various programmatic ways to do this).

Comment: This is not entirely true for IIS7+.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS 7.0+ this can be done very easily (although instead of recycling the Application Pool, it will terminate the process and then restart it when `resetInterval` has been reached). See:
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/cpu